# Visual Studios: Application Failed to Start Because Configuration is Incorrect, SxS Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sxs

I have a visual studios 2010 project, and it's compiling without any problem. When I go to run it, I'm encountering a:

> This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect.

This was compiling and running yesterday morning, but now it no longer does. I reverted back to the original version, but I'm still getting the same error.

I ran sxstrace, the output was:

```
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Tomato Analyzer 3.0.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Tomato Analyzer 3.0.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

I see that there are a lot of references to the debug CRT, but I have my project set to release mode, and I'm not linking to any external third-party libraries.

I've tried to reinstall visual studios, but that didn't work. Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: One thing is interesting is there are Visual Studio 2008 debug dlls in a Visual Studio 2010 project.

Comment: I'm confused by that. I don't have visual studios 2008 installed on my machine, and the target toolset is VS 2010. I have no idea why that is happening.